# What is the relation of word "simple" with math-word "simple group" of group theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology, simple-groups

Is there any relation with the meaning of word "simple" with what "there are groups $G$ in which the only normal subgroups are the trivial ones: $1$ and $G$. Such groups are called simple groups"$_1$ describes?

This might allow eliminating memory to know what the word "Simple group" describes, from the knowing of relation with word simple.

---

$_1$ Abstract Algebra, David S. Dummit, Richard M.Foote

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are asking. That's the definition of simple group: the only normal subgroups are itself and the trivial identity-only group.

Comment: @JairTaylor the OP asks why they are called SIMPLE groups and not anything else. Why _simple_?

Comment: Because you can't decompose them through quotienting. Like the elementary particles in Physics.

Comment: I seem to be getting certain relation now, from google meaning of word simple: "plain, basic, or uncomplicated in form, nature, or design; without much decoration or ornamentation.
"a simple white blouse"". Simple group or group is "plain, basic" with respect to its normal subgroups?

Comment: The meaning of simple here is as in "irreducible", "indecomposable", "primitive", "prime", etc.

Comment: You don’t have to worry about any normal subgroups and so your life is simpler.

Comment: A curious fact: in Russian (as well as Ukrainian, it seems, and some other languages), "prime" and "simple" are the same word, so such question doesn't arise.

Comment: I don't recommend learning math definitions by relating them to the ordinary meaning of words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One [dictionary entry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/simple) for simple is

> constituting a basic element
> not made up of many like units

One common way of decomposing groups is into a normal subgroup and the corresponding quotient group. Simple groups are simple because they cannot be decomposed like this in any meaningful way. Much the same way prime numbers cannot be factored in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 1):

The mathematical meaning of "*simple*" is not restricted to groups. It also applies to, say, Lie algebras (which are called *simple* if they do not have a proper nontrivial ideal). Also a ring is called *simple*, if it has no proper nontrivial two-sided ideal.
An algebraic group over a field $K$ is called *simple* if it is non-commutative and has no closed connected normal subgroups other than itself and the trivial group.
Furthermore, an object $X$ in a category $C$ with a zero object $0$ is *simple* if there are precisely two quotient objects of $X$ , namely $0$ and $X$.

In all cases, simple means that we cannot decompose anymore in a natural way.

Comment: And a module is called *simple* if it has no nontrivial proper submodules.