# What is the relation of word "centralizer" with math-word "centralizer of A in G" (where A is any non empty subset of group G) of group theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology

Is there any relation with the meaning of word "centralizer" with what

"Let A be any subset of (group) G.
Definition. Define $C_G (A)=\{g \space \epsilon \space G | \space gag^{-1}=a \space  \text{for all a}\space \epsilon A\}$. This subset of G is called the centralizer of A in G...."1

describes?

This might allow eliminating memory to know what the word "centralizer of A in G" describes, from the knowing of relation with word centralizer.

---

$_1$ Abstract Algebra, David S. Dummit, Richard M.Foote

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4674969/what-is-the-relation-of-word-simple-with-math-word-simple-group-of-group-the?noredirect=1#comment9882440_4674969

Comment: Well, $C_G(G)=Z(G)$ is helpful.

Comment: Well, the centralizer $C_G(A)$ ($G$ a group, $A \subseteq G$) is intimately related to the notion of the center of $G$, $Z(G)$:

$$Z(G) := \{ g \in G \mid \forall a \in G, ga=ag\}$$

i.e. the set of all elements commuting with every element of $G$. Of course, 

$$Z(G) = \bigcap_{g \in G} C_G(g) = Z(G)$$

Several explanations for *that* name ("center") are [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3075020/is-there-a-reason-why-zg-is-named-the-centre-of-a-group). The notion of a "centralizer" ("makes things central") is a natural extrapolation, IMO

Comment: @PrincessEev Thank you

Comment: @orione Thank you